# C# - From Text File to Array (Index out of bounds - StreamReader)

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

I am very new to programming and learning C# and I have encountered a problem with using array:

(Not using list)

I have a text file with three rows (Adam Evert Jonson) named names.txt, and I want to add these to an array that can hold three elements. When creating the array I am told the index is out of bounds. I guess I am missing something obvious, a loop or such?

This is for me learning StreamReader.

thank you for your time.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program {
public static void Main(string\[\] args) {
Names.Load();
 }
}

class Names {
string firstName;
string middleName;
string lastName;

public static void Load() {
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("names.txt");

string r;

while ((r = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
  string[] field = r.Split('\t');

  string firstName = field[0];
  string middleName = field[1];
  string lastName = field[2];

  Names m = new Names();
  m.firstName = firstName;
  m.middleName = middleName;
  m.lastName = lastName;
 }
  file.Close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Guessing there is a newline at the end of the file. This will return a blank line. You need to check that `field.Length == 3` after calling `Split()`. If not, skip that line.

Comment: check `serialization` in C#, this will auto map the properties from file

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Johnny Mopp, make sure there are three elements in the "field" array:

```
string[] field = r.Split('\t');
if (field.Length == 3) {
    string firstName = field[0];
    string middleName = field[1];
    string lastName = field[2];

    Names m = new Names();
    m.firstName = firstName;
    m.middleName = middleName;
    m.lastName = lastName;
    
    // "m" is local, so it won't be avaialble outside
    // the while loop, do something with it?
    // ... do something with "m" ...
}
```

You could also use `if (field.Length >= 3)`, to make sure there are AT LEAST THREE values in the array, and you would just be ignoring the rest.

If you only want to read that very first line, then exit the loop after getting your data.

Answer (score 0):

To read plain files such as .txt or .csv files I would recommend to use FileHelpers library.

You need to first install it through 'Manage NuGet Packages'

1. Hit the 'Browse' tab
2. Type 'FileHelpers'
3. Install the latest version your solution supports.

Then you would need to create a model class with the properties.

```
using FileHelpers;

[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Names
{
    public string firstName;

    public string middleName;

    public string lastName;

}
```

Your names.txt file should look something like:

```
Albus, Percival, Dumbledore
Albus, Severus, Potter
```

Where each line would be a 'Person' but will be parsed as your 'Names' class.

In your program class you need the next code:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Names>();

// To Read Use:
var result = engine.ReadFile("names.txt"); //You should put the route to your file here
// result is now an array of Names
```

You can see the result:

```
foreach (Names name in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Names:");
    Console.WriteLine(name.firstName + " - " + name.middleName+ " - " + name.lastName);
}
```

You can check more of this library in: [FileHelpers QuickStart](https://www.filehelpers.net/quickstart/)